# Publish Bicep module gives "The specified module reference scheme "'br" is not recognized"

Tags: azure-bicep, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to store a Bicep module in a Container Registry and follow the steps Microsoft share at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/share-bicep-modules-using-private-registries/5-exercise-publish-module-your-registry?pivots=cli.

But when I run the command below (directly copied from the MS Learn page)

`az bicep publish --file website.bicep --target 'br:myacr.azurecr.io/website:v1'`

I get an error saying

`The specified module reference scheme "'br" is not recognized. Specify a path to a local module file or a module reference using one of the following schemes: "br", "ts"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message in detail! The error say that `'br` is not recognized, so it is the starting `'` that is the problem here.

If you remove the enclosing '-chars the command will execute properly

`az bicep publish --file website.bicep --target br:myacr.azurecr.io/website:v1`